# What profit can you get from having a dummy?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

[Tehillim 30:10](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2630.htm)

מַה-בֶּצַע בְּדָמִי

What profit is there in a dummy?

I don't know ... perhaps this is a dum question? Is there any profit in having a dummy? Dum-de-dum-dum...

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I'm thinking one advantage of having a dummy is that they may qualify for SSI benefits.

Answer (score 4):

A Jewish ventriloquist once attended a Purim party with a dummy designed to look just like her.

**PROHIBITED!!** Shouted the rabbi. The Megillah says:

*Al TEDAMI VENAFSHECH!*

You may not make a dummy like yourself, young lady!

Comment: Clever! :-) +15

Answer (score 1):

There's definite value in having a dummy in contract bridge — provided you're good at the game. You see, the existence of a dummy adds an element of skill to the game, whose outcome would otherwise be highly dependent on the luck of the deal.

This presents a problem in *halacha*, though, as betting games in which someone expects to win (e.g. because of superior skill) can be [*asmachta*](/a/55848). Indeed, the *Gesher Hachayim* rules for this reason that one should play whist rather than contract bridge. He notes that there's an allusion to this from a verse in Tanach, but he refuses to name the verse because it's an *asmachta*.

Comment: I wish I could vote either way. But, as I am uneducated in contract bridge or "whist" (never heard of it), I can't do either. But, if you wish, you can provide a link to where the Gesher Hachayim (if such a person really exists, as I suspect you made up this name b/c of the word "gesher") says this.

Comment: @DanF There really is a book _Gesher Hachayim_. But it's about mourning. I stole the name because of the pun.

Answer (score 1):

In many expressways in metropolitan areas in U.S.A. (and I assume Israel and other countries, as well) you can use the HOV (high occupancy vehicle) lanes if you have at least 2 car occupants.

The beginning of the Tehillim that I cited says (verse 2):
ולא שםחת אויבי לי

You didn't make my enemies happy.

I don't know about you, but when I drive to work during rush hour, **every** other driver on the crowded highway is my enemy. But, to use the HOV lane, I have to have someone else in the car with me.

That's where the dummy comes in. I put in the car, and, voila, I can now use the fast HOV lane! And my enemies are not happy .. nope - not at all!

Too bad for them that most of them don't read M.Y. :-)

Comment: http://www.bostonglobe.com/metro/2014/05/08/state-trooper-this-commuter-was-real-dummy/SQON7a5wCdTVPSdEtokOwJ/story.html

Comment: @Shalom - Yes, I know that many have done this trick, before. Still, I'll bet my chulent that none of them have read M.Y. Some of the dummy descriptions are very clever and funny. Thanks for the link.